# For which vectors $(b_1 , b_2 , b_3)$ do these systems have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

For which vectors $(b_1 , b_2 , b_3)$ do these systems have a solution?
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ $\times$ $\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
b_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

I have to solve this without solving the system (how could you even solve the system, it says this times something equals something?) but I don't know how? Does this have something to do with column space? The column space of the first matrix would be all of $R^3$ but I don't know how that helps me figure out what the vector $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ is?
Is the question just asking for $b_1=x_1+x_2+x_3$,
$b_2=x_2+x_3$,
$b_3=x_3$?

Comment: Your matrix has rank 3, use it.

Comment: given $b_1, b_2, b_3,$ all you need to do is find out what $x_3, x_2, x_1$ must be.

Comment: @WillJagy so you mean $x_3=b_3$, $x_2=b_2-b_3$, and $x_1=b_1-b_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
b_3 \\
\end{bmatrix},$$
let $h_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1  \\0  \\0  \\\end{bmatrix},$ $h_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1  \\1  \\0  \\\end{bmatrix},$ $h_3 = \begin{bmatrix}1  \\1  \\1  \\\end{bmatrix}$,$b = \begin{bmatrix}b_1  \\b_2  \\b_3  \\\end{bmatrix}$ rewrite the initial system in the following form 
$$x_1h_1 + x_2h_2 + x_3h_3 = b,$$
so you have a linear combination of $h_1, h_2, h_3$, moreover it is not hard to notice that $h_1, h_2, h_3$ are linearly independent.

Here comes the question: having $3$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ how many vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you can represent as a linear combination of given independent vectors?

P.S. There is no need to inverse your matrix, since the question is to find all $b$ for which the solution exists.

Comment: if$h_1, h_2, and h_3$ are linearly independent then doesn't the mean there are an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: @idknuttin No, solution is one and only one. But it's not your question. Look, solution is the vector $x$. Vector $b$ is given, so the question is: for which given $b$ you can find $x$?

Comment: Is the answer to my original question what I wrote in my question about what $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ equal?

Comment: Your teacher may disagree with you since it wasn't your problem to find $x$. You have to use some fundamental properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to state that: it doesn't matter which $b$ I receive, I can always find $x$.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant $b_1=x_1+x_2+x_3$,   
$b_2=x_2+x_3$,   
$b_3=x_3$

Comment: What your wrote is just another way to write a system of linear equations.

Comment: You do not need to find vector $b$, because it's given.

Comment: So what does the question "For which vectors (b1,b2,b3)(b1,b2,b3) do these systems have a solution?" mean? I don't think I am understanding the question it is asking?

Comment: Do you know when it is possible to inverse a matrix?

Comment: as long as there isn't a zero where a pivot should be if it can't be fixed by row swapping

Answer (score 1):

The system has solution iff $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & b_1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & b_2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & b_3 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$ this matrix has rank $3$ for the [Rouché-Capelli's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite these equations as:

$ b_3 = x_3 ,\\$
$ b_2 - b_3 = x_2, b_1 - b_2 = x_1$

It's the same as inverting the given matrix!!

Comment: So I state the solution as this system only has solutions for vectors $x_3=b_3$, $x_2=b_2-b_3$, and $x_1=b_1-b_2$?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is  matrix $n \times n$, $x$ is the $n \times 1$ matrix variable and $b$ a $n \times 1$ matrix given, then the system
$$ A . x = b$$
has  solution ever that $A$  is invertible. Since, your problem has ever solution.